# Android launchin thridparty intent not working

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I 'm trying to launch the camera app on button click but I don't want to hav the fot
I want it to behave like it is launched by the lauc´ncher but when I call my code the application simply closes and the camera isn't starting.There isn't even an error code.

Code :

```
if(v == camera)
    {

        //Intent in=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 

            // this.startActivity(in);



        Intent startupIntent = new Intent();
        ComponentName distantActivity = new ComponentName("com.android.camera","com.android.camera/.Camera");
        startupIntent.setComponent(distantActivity);
        startupIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startActivity(startupIntent);    


        finish();
    }
```

Comment: make sure you have add <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.CAMERA" />  in manifest ?

Comment: do i have to a this permission for only launching the intent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `android.intent.action.VIEW` instead of `Intent.ACTION_MAIN` as:

```
    Intent startupIntent = new Intent();

    ComponentName distantActivity= new ComponentName("YOUR_CAMRA_APP_PACKAGE","YOUR_CAMRA_APP_PACKAGE.ACTIVTY_NAME");

// LIKE IN LG  DEVICE WE HAVE AS

//ComponentName distantActivity= new //ComponentName("com.lge.camera","com.lge.camera.CameraApp");

    startupIntent .setComponent(distantActivity);

    startupIntent .setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");

    startActivity(startupIntent);
```

Comment: ok what happening when you are running this code any error then post your logcat stacktrace

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.camera/com.android.camera.Camera}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: you known your mobile default camera app package name and main activity name?

Comment: bez in my lg device i have com.lge.camera and just confirm by attaching your device to log cat and then launch camera app on device

Comment: but how can i do a work around and get the right pacckage name ?

Comment: attach your device to logcat in eclipse ans launch default camera app on device then you will see full application name in log cat